# Google sheets - Installable Triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run the onChange function below using triggers but keeps failing.

The error is:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSheet') at onChange(Code:161:21)` Line 161 is `var sheet = range.getSheet();`

My function:

````
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == 'SMS' && range.getRow() > 1 && range.getColumn() < 3) {
    var colA = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
    var colB = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).getValue();
    if (colA != '' && colB != '') {
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 3).setFormula("='SMS Text'!$B$1");
    }
  }
}```

Triggers settings are:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


I have also tried:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjjDm.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gynFP.png
````

Comment: The event object for onChange and onEdit trigger is a lot different.

Comment: You will need to replace e.range somehow because onChange does not supply a range value.

Comment: Thanks - any advice how to replace e.range to get this fuction to work as intended.

Comment: That's not an option.  There is no remedy except to use the event objects that are available to us.  I  suppose if you wish you bring it up as an issue to google you can find a link to issues - [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 0):

**Differences in onEdit and onChange event objects**

```
function onMyEdit(e){Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))};
//{"authMode":"FULL","oldValue":"10.0","range":{"columnEnd":6,"columnStart":6,"rowEnd":6,"rowStart":6},"source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""},"value":"pp"}


function onMyChange(e){Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))};
//{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"EDIT","source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}
```

> onChange event object does  not supply a range value

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Trigger Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)